# Why is this VB program always returning 1 as page number?

Tags: regex, vb.net, vba, ms-word

This program finds certain words in a MS Word document using the RegExp method.  Once each match is found, the program is supposed to find the page of each match and create a string that can be output to show all pages where that keyword match was found. The way it's written now, for some reason it's outputting a "1" for each page no matter what page it's found on.  For example, if the word "Mouse" was found on page 1, 5, and 22, it would output 1, 1, 1,.

```
For Each Match In RegExp.Execute(oWord.ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
            myKeyWords(numKeywords) = Match.Value
    PageNumbers(numKeywords) = ""

    With myWordDoc.ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = Match.value
        .Wrap = False
        .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute = True
           If PageNumbers(numKeywords) = "" Then
               PageNumbers(numKeywords) = oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           Else
              PageNumbers(numKeywords) = PageNumbers(numKeywords) & ", " & oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           End If
        Loop
    End With
```

Comment: I guess your problem is PageNumbers(numKeywords) is always "". You will need to evaluate this method and/or numKeywords to make sure they are both producing expected results. Also instead of SourceString = SourceString + ",.." you can write the expression as SourceString += ",.." it's tidier and saves typing.

Comment: PageNumbers(numKeywords) isn't always ""  It's actually changing during the If Else statement, but is reset each time the For Each Match statement starts.  Thanks for the other info though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numKeywords isn't incrementing.  I've written it out without the

```
For Each Match In RegExp.Execute(oWord.ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
```

Here it is, be aware that if you take this function outside of the regexp method that you'll need to change the .Text = myKeywords(x) and remove the .range before find.

```
PageNumbers(numKeywords) = ""
For x = LBound(myKeywords) To UBound(myKeywords)
    PageNumbers(x) = ""
    With myWordDoc.ActiveDocument.Find
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = myKeywords(x)
        .Wrap = False
        .Forward = True
        Do While .Execute = True
           If PageNumbers(numKeywords) = "" Then
               PageNumbers(numKeywords) = oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           Else
              PageNumbers(numKeywords) = PageNumbers(numKeywords) & ", " & oWord.Selection.Information(Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
           End If
        Loop
    End With
```